# DirectWrite ScriptAnalysis get script name from index

Tags: winapi, directx, sharpdx, text-rendering, directwrite

DirectWrite [ScriptAnalysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwrite/ns-dwrite-dwrite_script_analysis) Contains a UINT16 number that is zero-based index representation of writing system script.

How can I know the name of the script?
For example in English the number is equal to 49, and in Russian the number is equal to 22.

Is there a table of all languages somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `IDWriteTextAnalyzer1::GetScriptProperties()` you'll get ISO codes.
The table of languages can be found on the Unicode.org site.
It is called "Codes for the representation of names of scripts"
Here is the link for that:
http://unicode.org/iso15924/iso15924-codes.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IDWriteTextAnalyzer1::GetScriptProperties()`, it will return script info for given script analysis result. If you need a display name instead of script ISO codes, you'll need your own mapping table.